# Как снять голос с приложения ВКонтакте на PHP?

Tags: вконтакте, php, vkontakte-api, iframe

Есть приложение ВКонтакте (IFRAME), на него через `VK.callMethod('showPaymentBox', 1);` внесён 1 голос и пользователь его видит как:

[image]

т.е его можно в любой момент снять. Но как на PHP написать полное снятие этого голоса, чтобы его уже было нереально снять? Помогите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: тебе к брату к Дурову :)

Comment: vk.com/developers.php#devstep2

Comment: Crasher, какая функция именно? Я не могу найти...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [`secure.withdrawVotes`](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=secure.withdrawVotes). Описание:

> Списывает голоса со счета пользователя на счет приложения (в сотых долях).